# I cannot draw on my canvas

Tags: canvas

I've been trying to draw on a basic canvas with html but I cannot seem to do it. I have seen a lot of tutorials all of which didn't seem to help me in drawing on the canvas. I have also looked up on the internet to try and find an answer. In the process I wrote some of the script which has some of the tutorials amalgamated 
together.

```
function draw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mindmap");
    var myCanvas = canvas.getContext("2d");

    myCanvas.fillStyle = 'black';
    myCanvas.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the whole canvas to become black but it doesn't work for me.

The complete code is here:

```
    <html>
        <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
    charset=windows-1252">
            <title>Title</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                #header{
                    background-color:rgb(200, 150, 150);
                    font-family: monospace;
                    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
                }
                canvas{
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
            function draw(){
                var c = document.getElementById("mindmap");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="header">Title</h1>
            <canvas id="mindmap" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <p>My canvas work</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? How do you call your function? A basic example works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vb60j3q4/

Comment: Please provide a more complete code example and specify any errors you're getting in your browser console

Comment: @j08691 I don't see any errors in the console and I don't call the `draw()` function like you did in your example. I tried implementing it in my work but nothing still happened.

Comment: @Amy, there are no console errors in the browser and I have put the full code up.

Comment: The JS won't do anything until you call the `draw()` function.

Comment: @KelechiMba Functions don't do anything until you call them.

Answer (score -1):

That code looks good, it should draw just fine.

The only thing that could be tripping you is the id of the canvas...
Make sure the `mindmap` is the canvas id.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mindmap");
var myCanvas = canvas.getContext("2d");

myCanvas.fillStyle = 'black';
myCanvas.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
myCanvas.fillRect(40, 40, 20, 20);
myCanvas.fillRect(65, 65, 20, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="mindmap"></canvas>
```